# Can I upgrade from Drupal 6.19 straight to Drupal 7.34?

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, upgrade

I noticed my site is outdated (Drupal 6.19).

I was wondering if I need to upgrade to Drupal 6.34 first before I upgrade to the newest 7.34.
Or can I just go ahead and upgrade to 7.34?

Is there anything I should keep in consideration so I don't do this wrong?
Any links as to where can I start off with Drupal 6.19 to upgrade it to 7.34?

Thank you much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to update your current Drupal version before performing a major upgrade.

Before attempting this upgrade, you should probably give this page a good look-see, as it has lots of information that you'll need to know.

https://www.drupal.org/upgrade

On that page it will also point you in the direction of reading the UPGRADING.txt which comes in each Drupal source package.

And do not forget to backup both your drupal install & database before attempting the upgrade.

Comment: Can I use the database from my Drupal 6 site on my Drupal 7 site?

Comment: Yes, you supposed to have the same Drupal 6 database, upgrade process will modify the DB structure.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 have some big differences so I'm not sure how you planned to do that. Don't think that it will work. To lates D6 version yes, but D6 to D7...hardly. Good luck, but make backup of your site first!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a template that was built specifically for that version you might have to update that but other than that i suppose you could get away with a straight forward upgrade.

Comment: The site is currently using a theme based off the "zen" theme.